# Click on link with Selenium Webdriver Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, random

I need to get all the links from specific div, and randomly click on one of them.
My code is wrong, because I'm trying to click on str object, but idk other solution.

```
links = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.product-grid a")
links_list=[]
for element in links:
    links_list.append(element.get_attribute("href"))

random.choice(links_list).click()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was easier than expected

```
links = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.product-grid a")
random.choice(links).click()
```